# Why does sbt-scoverage report java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate mappings for JavaScript files?

Tags: playframework, sbt, scoverage

I am using [sbt-scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage) plugin for a project written in Play Framework.

I'm facing the following `java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate mappings` error:

```
[scoverage]: Instrumentation completed [35097 statements]
[scoverage]: Written instrumentation file [/Users/project/target/scala-2.10/scoverage-data/scoverage.coverage.xml]
[scoverage]: Writing measurements data to [/Users/project/target/scala-2.10/scoverage-data]
...
[info] Compiling 49 Scala sources to /Users/project/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate mappings:
/Users/project/target/scala-2.10/scoverage-classes/services-main.js
from
/Users/project/target/scala-2.10/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/global/services/services-main.js
/Users/project/target/scala-2.10/resource_managed/main/public/javascripts/kiosk/global/services/services-main.js
/Users/project/target/scala-2.10/scoverage-classes/global.min.css
from......
```

My guess is that it's trying to transfer `service-main.js` from somewhere in the `target` under `scoverage-classes`. I do not intend to run scoverage against any JavaScript file so I included the following setting:

```
ScoverageKeys.excludedPackages in ScoverageCompile := ".views.;.javascripts.;.assets.;.js.;.resource_managed."
```

It changes nothing - the error persists. How do I instruct scoverage to ignore JavaScript files?

Comment: Is this a multimodule project? Do you have `services-main.js` under `app/assets/javascripts` **and** `app/assets/javascripts/kiosk` folders? Where does the `kiosk` folder come from? Do you use `sbt-rjs`? What about `project/plugins.sbt`?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but worth pursuing to check if it fixes the issue.

According to [Exclude classes and packages](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage#exclude-classes-and-packages):

> You can exclude classes from being considered for coverage measurement
>   by providing semicolon-separated list of regular expressions.
>
> The regular expressions are matched against the fully qualified class
>   name, and must match the entire string to take effect.
>
> Any matched classes will not be instrumented or included in the
>   coverage report.

I think the regular expressions you use are incorrect and since they don't match they are of no effect. Use `.*` not `.` as follows:

```
ScoverageKeys.excludedPackages in ScoverageCompile := ".*javascripts.*;.*\.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in release 1.0.0. Note that the config changed so be sure to check the readme (most notably, the command to run changed from `sbt scoverage:test` to `sbt coverage test` and the plugin became an auto plugin so you don't need to add instrumentSettings anymore).

https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage